# Splitting json based on pipe symbol in android

Tags: android, json

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58a7d985aecc2",
      "fullname": "testing",
      "score": "10",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "10",
      "accuracy": "0"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58d34fcf6013d",
      "fullname": "sbbzbz",
      "score": "9",
      "user_photo": "58d34fcf6013d_1492427518007.jpg",
      "time_taken": "16",
      "accuracy": "4"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58d34fb18f799",
      "fullname": "vby",
      "score": "9",
      "user_photo": "58d34fb18f799_1492428670471.jpg",
      "time_taken": "36",
      "accuracy": "2"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58bf9e2851aa6",
      "fullname": " chec",
      "score": "8",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "9",
      "accuracy": "6"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58a300a9005a4",
      "fullname": "Student1 ",
      "score": "8",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "11",
      "accuracy": "2"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58cb5f835c456",
      "fullname": "reg",
      "score": "8",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "62",
      "accuracy": "2"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58bfca20c5d04",
      "fullname": "study",
      "score": "7",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "12",
      "accuracy": "2"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58c255adad156",
      "fullname": "st",
      "score": "7",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "57",
      "accuracy": "4"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58be3a08a92d9",
      "fullname": "test",
      "score": "6",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "11",
      "accuracy": "2"
    },
    {
      "uniq_uid": "58bfcae0ed0c3",
      "fullname": "student2 ",
      "score": "5",
      "user_photo": "",
      "time_taken": "9",
      "accuracy": "2"
    }
  ]
}||0
```

Comment: You want to remove pipe symbol from json

Comment: Nop...I want to store the pipe symbol before part in one arraylist and the pipesymbol after part in another arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Store the json in a string and split that string into parts based on symbol by using the following code.

```
String string = "001|023151"
String[] parts = string.split("|");
String part1 = parts[0]; // 001
String part2 = parts[1]; // 023151
```

(You can replace the "|" with anything on the basis of which you want to divide your string)

Answer (score 1):

You can use split() method.

String [] myArray = data.split("|");

Answer (score 0):

String[] data = yourJson.split("|"); //change to || if need it

Answer (score 0):

```
    String response = **Your Jsondata;**
        String[] values = string.split("|");
        String res_1 = values [0];
        String res_2 = values [1]; 

//Json Parsing


    object = new JSONObject(res_1);
                    if (object.has("response")) {
                        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(object.getString("response"));
                        shopList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject row = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                           DataModel data = new  DataModel();
                            data.setSeller_id(row.getString("uniq_uid"));
                            data.setSeller_name(row.getString("fullname"));
                            data.setStoretitle(row.getString("score"));
                            data.setStoreURL(row.getString("user_photo"));                             
                        data.setSeller_country(row.getString("time_taken"));
                            data.setState(row.getString("accuracy"));
                            shopList.add(data);
                        }


                }
```

Comment: When I print the value of pres_2 I am getting only the open curly bracket

Comment: The same result

Comment: did u create model or not? and also check the get valid json response or not use jsonlint.com find its valid response or not

Answer (score 0):

```
 String response = **Your Jsondata;**
        response=response.replace("||0","");
//Json Parsing


    object = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (object.has("response")) {
                        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(object.getString("response"));
                        shopList = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject row = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                           DataModel data = new  DataModel();
                            data.setSeller_id(row.getString("uniq_uid"));
                            data.setSeller_name(row.getString("fullname"));
                            data.setStoretitle(row.getString("score"));
                            data.setStoreURL(row.getString("user_photo"));                             
                        data.setSeller_country(row.getString("time_taken"));
                            data.setState(row.getString("accuracy"));
                            shopList.add(data);
                        }


                }
```